# Proper python way to: Work on original in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a ndarray 'n_data' of floats with shape(N, 3). I want to itterate and make changes to 'n_data' (Not a copy). I have the following code witch works, but it feels very dirty:

```
    i = 0
    for point in n_data:
        point -= center

        r = np.linalg.norm(point)
        n_data[i] = point * (r ** gamma / r)

        i += 1
```

I tried using np.nditer, but for each iteration it would get a single number and not a ndarray with shape(3,) as above.

```
        for point in np.nditer(n_data, op_flags=['readwrite']):

        point -= center

        r = np.linalg.norm(point)
        point = point * (r ** gamma / r)
```

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: `nditer` is generally better in `c` code than in python. I'd use `for i, row in enumerate(arr):` if I had to iterate on rows and also needed an index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One vectorized version of the translation to *NumPy terms* and still look close enough to the original code would be with making use of [`NumPy broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and using the optional argument `axis` parameter with `np.linalg.norm`, like so -

```
shifted = n_data - center
R = np.linalg.norm(shifted, axis=1, keepdims=1)
n_data = shifted * (R ** gamma / R)
```

Hope this feels less *dirty*!

Comment: Tested your suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks for a good answer, I'll give broadcasting a read ;-)